# CALayer change borderColor on UIControlState change

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, calayer

I have a customized button that has a transparent background and a custom border set in the button's `layer`.

I want to change the border color of the button to a darker color when the button is pressed, e.g. during `UIControlStateSelected`, but I can't find an easy way to do this.

Is this possible? Or do I need to find a workaround for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can listen to an event like `UIControlEventTouchDown` and configure the border when it occurs. You need to add an observer as follows:

```
[yourButton addTarget:self
               action:@selector(configureBorderIn)
     forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
```

You should add an observer to configure the border when the button is released, for example detecting `UIControlEventTouchUpInside`. You have a list of all events related to buttons here: [UIControl class reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIControl_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UIControl).

Hope it helps!
have a good day.